# Why is my contact form not sending back to my domain

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, contact-form

Im creating a contact form for my website using Actionscript 3.0 with Flash CS6, I have my code written down perfectly but in order to receive my messages towards my email ain't working :( Here is my code

```
<?php


$emailTo    = "myemail@myemail.com";
$name       = $_POST["Patrick"];
$emailFrom  = $_POST["myemail@myemail.com"];
$message    = $_POST["Hello"];
$subject    = "From Contact Form";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $body  = "Name: "     . $name .      "\n\n";
    $body .= "Email: "    . $emailFrom . "\n\n";
    $body .= "Message:\n" . $message;
    $body  = wordwrap($body, 70);
    $header = "From: " . $emailFrom . "\nReply-To: " . $emailFrom. "\n\n";

if(mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $header)) {
    echo("result=Successful");
} else {
    echo("result=Unsuccessful");
}

}
?>
```

Thanks and hope I you guys can help me

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in how you try to retrieve the `$_POST` variables.

You're code suggests that you post fields with the names `Patrick`, `myemail@myemail.com` and `Hello`. That wouldn't be logical.

So I guess that your code should be something like the following:

```
$emailTo    = "myemail@myemail.com";
$name       = $_POST["name"];
$emailFrom  = $_POST["emailFrom"];
$message    = $_POST["message"];
$subject    = "From Contact Form";
```

Or for *testing purposes* (just to see if your mail script is working):

```
$emailTo    = "myemail@myemail.com";
$name       = "Patrick";
$emailFrom  = "myemail@myemail.com";
$message    = "Hello";
$subject    = "From Contact Form";
```